# Creating a Map from SOQL missing field in Map

Tags: apex, soql, map

I am creating a map from a SOQL Query and the map does not have all of the columns in it. I am not sure why this is.

```
 For(Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c objSSA : 
       [Select Country__c, State_Province__c, User__c
            From Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c                                                                                  
       Where Country__c =: pstrCountry 
            And (State_Province__c =: pstrState or State_Province__c = '')]
      )
                  
   mapSalesforceSalesAssignments.put(objSSA.Country__c, objSSA);



 system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG:   mapSalesforceSalesAssignments              ' + mapSalesforceSalesAssignments);
```

In the Debug Logs I can see that State_Province__c is not in the map. How can I get State_Province__c to be in the map?

```
13:41:04:462 USER_DEBUG [72]|DEBUG|DEBUG: Start  Loop 1  mapSalesforceSalesAssignments              {Germany=Salesforce_Sales_Assignments__c:{Country__c=Germany, User__c=005U00000013MZyIAM, Id=a3J4P000001c3OdUAI}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug the map it will only show the **fields which has value** (means which is not null). If you want to check if the empty filed is coming or not then you can debug it separately.

Below is the code example:

```
System.debug(mapSalesforceSalesAssignments.get(objSSA.Country__c).State_Province__c);
```

Comment: It has a value that kinda the problem.

Comment: did you try to print it separately because I can see from your query State_Province__c =: pstrState or State_Province__c = '' which means State_Province__c  can be null or empty

Comment: Yes... I triple checked. Makes no sense

Comment: in that case try to check if you have permission for that field

Comment: I am doing it as System Admin and Running it as System Admin

Comment: When you are trying to print System.debug(mapSalesforceSalesAssignments.get(objSSA.Country__c).State_Province__c);
 is it giving you any error?

Comment: I was getting 2 records back.... One with State/Prov filled out and one that wasnt. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Always Happy to help :)